# Why is a Hibernate JPQL Type Cast necessary for String

Tags: hibernate, playframework, jpa-2.0, jpql

I am using the Play! Framework for a small application. In a Model I have the following Query:

```
public static ApplicationUser getByUserName(String userName) {
    return ApplicationUser.find("SELECT u FROM ApplicationUser u WHERE u.userName = ?", userName).first();
}
```

This works perfectly with the in memory DB H2 but when I use Postgres I get the following error:

```
22:57:10,371 WARN  ~ SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
22:57:10,371 ERROR ~ ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 167
```

When I cast the parameter like:

```
ApplicationUser.find("SELECT u FROM ApplicationUser u WHERE u.userName = CAST(? AS string)", userName).first()
```

Then it works. But why is this necessary. Could that be a Hibernate bug?

**Update:**
I downgraded the play Version from 1.2.4 to 1.2.3 and now it works. I think the problem lies in the shipped postgres jdbc driver probably.

**Update II**: The problem is still not solved. I get the same error again for the query:

```
ApplicationRole.find("byName", name).first();
```

The error:

```
JPAQueryException occured : Error while executing query SELECT u FROM ApplicationUser u WHERE u.userName = ?: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea   Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

In `application.conf` I have:

> jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Nobody having this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the *?* by *(?1)* as in:

```
public static ApplicationUser getByUserName(String userName) {
    return ApplicationUser.find("SELECT u FROM ApplicationUser u WHERE u.userName = (?1)", userName).first();
}
```

I have a similar query and works just fine. I'm assuming the field *userName* in ApplicationUser is of type String (just in case!)

Also, as Dominik suggested, check that your *jpa.dialect* is set to auto-discover or to PosgreSQL.

Comment: See my Update. I have downgraded play from 1.2.4 to 1.2.3 now everything works fine.

Comment: That helped me now. Thanks. Sorry for the late answer

Answer (score 4):

have you enabled the postgresql database dialect in conf/application.conf ?

jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

Comment: See my Update. I have downgraded play from 1.2.4 to 1.2.3 now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the exact same problem, 1.2.4.

```
User.find("byEmail", email).first()
```

gets that exact same casting error as you, so I had to replace it with (thanks Pere)

```
User.find("email = (?1)", email).first()
```

Interestingly,

```
User.find("byEmailAndPassword", email, password).first()
```

still works...